# How to apply different margins on two types of links using BEM?

Tags: html, css, bem

I have a nav block. This nav block contains two different kinds of links. Local links and Social links. The local links need a margin-bottom while the social links need a margin-right.

To apply the margins, would I have to add modifiers on the links? If so, what would be the best name for these two modifiers?

```css
.nav__item--locals {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav__item--socials {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">

  <ul class="nav__locals">
    <li class="nav__item--locals"></li>
    <li class="nav__item--locals"></li>
    <li class="nav__item--locals"></li>
    <li class="nav__item--locals"></li>
  </ul>
  
  <ul class="nav__socials">
    <li class="nav__item--socials"></li>
    <li class="nav__item--socials"></li>
    <li class="nav__item--socials"></li>
  </ul>
  
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of,

- [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/) AND
- [BEM's Website](https://en.bem.info/) (mainly)

> From [Key-Val Modifiers](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#key-value),
>
> - Used when the modifier value is important. For example, "a menu with the islands design theme": menu_theme_islands.
> - The structure of the modifier's full name follows the pattern:
> - - `block-name_modifier-name_modifier-value`
> - - `block-name__element-name_modifier-name_modifier-value`

So, I think You should use this type of name,

```
.nav__item_lnk-type_locals
.nav__item_lnk-type_socials
```